# HTTP GET Request using ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic3

I am new to ionic i am trying to fetch result using REST API , with GET Method but not successfull , I am stuck into this problem from the last two days

can anyone please help me.

My code is here

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic Ok9AYWNsZUAxMjM=');
    headers.append('AuthUser', '78909890');
    headers.append('SecretKey','a8658f0d67890459');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.get('https:I/v01/?=AttachmentFiles')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data =>
  {

    this.posts = data["value"]; 
    console.log('GET RESPONSE',this.posts +"");
  });
```

i am getting error

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ommunicationPage -> Http]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ommunicationPage -> Http]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Http! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[mmunicationPage -> Http]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[mmunicationPage -> Http]:

My App Module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { DashboardPage } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import { AppDashboardPage } from '../pages/app-dashboard/app-dashboard';
import { WorkHistoryPage } from '../pages/work-history/work-history';
import { ElBalancePage } from '../pages/el-balance/el-balance';
import { LearningTabPage } from '../pages/learning-tab/learning-tab';
import { MandatoryTrainigsPage } from '../pages/mandatory-trainigs/mandatory-trainigs';
import { PastDueTrainingsPage } from '../pages/past-due-trainings/past-due-trainings';
import { ActiveTrainigsPage } from '../pages/active-trainigs/active-trainigs';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { BasicDetailsPage } from '../pages/basic-details/basic-details';
import { PersonalDetailsPage } from '../pages/personal-details/personal-details';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MangerViewPage } from '../pages/manger-view/manger-view';
import { Navbar } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';
import { Logger } from 'angular2-logger/core';
import { RestApiProvider } from '../providers/rest-api/rest-api';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import {HelpmetModalPage} from '../pages/helpmet-modal/helpmet-modal';
import {HelpMatePage} from '../pages/help-mate/help-mate';
import {SoftLoanPage} from '../pages/soft-loan/soft-loan';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    DashboardPage,
    LoginPage,
    AppDashboardPage,
    WorkHistoryPage,
    ElBalancePage,
    LearningTabPage,
    MandatoryTrainigsPage,
    PastDueTrainingsPage,
    ActiveTrainigsPage,
    TabsPage,
    BasicDetailsPage,
    PersonalDetailsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ChartsModule,
    FormsModule,
    SuperTabsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { tabsPlacement: 'top', }),
    SuperTabsModule.forRoot()
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    DashboardPage,
    AppDashboardPage,
    WorkHistoryPage,
    ElBalancePage,
    LearningTabPage,
    MandatoryTrainigsPage,
    PastDueTrainingsPage,
    CorpCommunicationPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Logger,
    RestApiProvider,
    InAppBrowser,
    Deeplinks,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please Help me
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: could you show AppModule

Comment: @Astacius check my updated question

Comment: what does your component and its `constructor()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should import `HttpModule` in app.module.ts like

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

...

imports: [
    HttpModule,
],
```

Comment: you are mixing httpClient and old http approach

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to import so many things in your `app,module.ts`.

Example Http Get:

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

Don't import HttpClient and HttpHeaders

```
getSomething(){

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', this.someToken);
  headers.append('Something', this.somethingElse);

  this.http.get('URL', {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
    }); 
  }
```

And you call it like this:

```
this.someServiceWithMethod.getSomething().then((data) => {
          this.something = data;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("something went wrong");
    });
```

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name 'resolve'. and [ts] Cannot find name 'reject'.

Comment: @user9483522 so just remove this part, but this is how it should be done

Comment: I have tried all the things,
Can you tell me the get request implementation using headers with example? Please

Comment: @user9483522 added

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **HttpClient** then why you have also imported **Http** from @angular/http?

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
```

Use this HttpClient for get request. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

    export class YourComponent {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    YourMethod(name) {
        const params = new HttpParams().set('name',name);
        const httpOptions = {
             headers: new HttpHeaders(
                { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
               )
           };
        this.http.get(GET_API_URL , { params: params }, httpOptions).subscribe(res => {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
       });
    }

}
```

> Best practise : Define api calls in a separate Service Class.